# Is there a function that, given a rational function, will return the general term of its infinite series expansion?

Tags: series-expansion

Is here some way to expand a rational function to an infinite sum in *Mathematica*, i.e., a series? I want the general term of the series.

For example, $\dfrac{2}{3(x-1)^3}$

Comment: How about `Series`?

Comment: Series works, but I was wondering if there was a function that converts the fraction straight to an infinite sum, in sum notation, not expanded out.

Comment: What would be your expected result?

Comment: @Henry: do you mean "rational function" (or even just "function") rather than "fraction"?

Answer (score 11):

In Mathematica 10 you can use `SeriesCoefficient` and `Inactive` to get what you require

```
Inactive[Sum][SeriesCoefficient[2/(3(x-1)^3),{x,0,n},Assumptions->n>=0]x^n,{n,0,\[Infinity]}]
```

where `Inactive` prevents `Sum` from evaluating.

You can then "activate" the `Sum` as follows

```
Activate[%]
```

to get back to your original expression.